# WebUiBuiltInKeywords.findWebElement() not working, WebElementNotFoundException

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

```
@Keyword
def reportsDropdownTest(TestObject drop) {
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
    WebElement ele = WebUiBuiltInKeywords.findWebElement(drop);
}
```

When I run this ^^ custom keyword in a katalon test case I receive this error:

```
Web element with id: 'Object Repository/Page_DITPRDADMS - DADMS Reports/Networks/available' located by 'By.xpath: //select[@id='source']' not found
```

The object I am trying to test on is this:

```
<select name="sourceColumns" class="sourceSelect" id="source" size="10" multiple="multiple" ondblclick="optionMove('source', 'destination', 'autoSuggestForm-1');return false;" onfocus="this.parentNode.className='sourceSelectShadowContainer';" onblur="this.parentNode.className='sourceSelectContainer';">...</select>
```

When I use built in keywords such as click or verify element present on this same object, I do not receive an error and the test step is successful.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the issue. Can you share your whole test script?

Comment: Do you have HTML frame over `select` tag?